# What is the distribution of the product of these two R.V?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable with gaussian distribution $N$ ($\mu$, $\sigma^2$).  Suppose $Z$ is a Bernoulli $B(p)$, independent of $X$. Find the distribution of
$Y = (2Z − 1)X$

Here is my attempt:

$P(Y \leq y)= P((2Z-1)X \leq y)= P((2Z-1)X\leq
 y|Z=0)P(Z=1)+P( (2Z-1)X\leq y|Z=1)P(Z=0)=P(X\geq-y)p+P(X\leq y)(1-p)$

We know that if $X$ is standard normal then, I can claim that $P(X\geq-y) =P(X\leq y)$, so that $P(Y \leq y)=P(X\leq y)$ which is the cdf of a normal. But what if $X$ was not standard normal?

Comment: I think $P(Z=0)=1-p$ and $P(Z=1) = p$.

Comment: Ok, you are right, but other than that? What distribution has Y? Is it normal?

Comment: @Alchemy Consider accepting answers that are helpful. Accepting an answer serves as an indication to future readers that it is correct.

Comment: I always do it. Are you referring to something in particular? Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @Alchemy Actually, you haven't accepted any answer so far.

Comment: I am sorry, you are right. I thought that giving up-vote was sufficient. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $S := 2Z-1$, and $X = \mu + \sigma W$, where $W$ is a standard normal random variable. We have $Y=SX$.
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(Y \leq y) &= \mathbb{P}(Y \leq y|S = +1)\mathbb{P}(S = +1) + \mathbb{P}(Y \leq y|S = -1)\mathbb{P}(S = -1)\\
&= p\mathbb{P}(\mu + \sigma W \leq y) + (1-p) \mathbb{P}(\mu + \sigma W \geq -y)\\
&= p\mathbb{P}\left( W \leq \frac{y-\mu}{\sigma}\right) + (1-p) \left[1 - \mathbb{P}\left(W < -\frac{y+\mu}{\sigma}\right) \right]\\
&=p \Phi\left( \frac{y-\mu}{\sigma}\right) +(1-p) \left[  1 - \Phi\left(-\frac{y+\mu}{\sigma}\right) \right]
\end{align}
where $\Phi$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution.
The pdf of $Y$ is therefore
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dy}\mathbb{P}(Y \leq y) &= \frac{1}{\sigma} \left[ p\; \phi\left( \frac{y-\mu}{\sigma}\right) + (1-p)\phi\left(-\frac{y+\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right]
\end{align}
where $\phi$ is the pdf of the standard normal distribution.

Comment: So it is pretty much right my attempt. Thank you very much.